# Order a text file in alphabetical order using the second column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, text-files, alphabetical-sort

I have tried all kinds of ways to get the text file to order alphabetically by the last name. The last name is currently read as column two of each split line. I can sort by column one without a problem. I try to put last.sort() or use the sorted(myList) but it doesn't work. I have even tried importing itemgetter. Please help! [Pictures of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMJO7.png)... [previous results with column one sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHGne.png)... [Picture of Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkIDZ.png)

**TXT FILE INFO:**
654,Jones,1,18:03
733,Smith,3,18:09
394,Jackson,4,18:22
876,Cole,1,18:23
555,Cruz,5,18:28
741,Martinez,2,18:33
499,Davis,2,18:36
338,Blunt,3,18:44
632,Patton,5,18:45
712,Joyce,4,18:49
112,Shoemaker,1,18:55
321,Smart,5,18:58
564,Love,2,19:01
843,Grove,4,19:05
933,Ham,3,19:10

```
with open("Race_Results_Sample.txt", "r")as myList:
    myList= myList.read().split()
    sorted(myList, key=lambda kv: kv[1])
    for line in myList:
        num, last, org, time = line.split(",")
        print num, last, org, time
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of the first ten lines or so of your text file?

Comment: You are originally splitting by spaces and later splitting by comma. You probably need to do the same type of split in each case. Try changing `.split()` to `.split(',')`.

Comment: I have tried to change the first .split() to include the ',' but it errors: IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parsing the text into a 2d List, something like

```
with open("test.txt", "r")as myList:
    myList = myList.read()
    myList = [l.split(",") for l in myList.splitlines()]
    myList = sorted(myList, key=lambda kv: kv[1])
    for line in myList:
        num, last, org, time = line
        print num, last, org, time
```

Split per linebreak and then again for each line per comma.

Comment: This works perfectly!!! Thank you so very much!! I have been trying all day to get this to work.